# How do I disable auto-test in WebStorm?

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I cant find any toggle button or settings menu that allows me to disable Mocha from running every time I change a file in WebStorm. I want to only run tests manually.

Is there a way to modify this behavior? And if so how?

Comment: what WebStorm version do you use? Since 2017.3, no 'Toggle auto-test' action is available for Mocha, re-running is handled by mocha itself: if `--watch` is specified in run configuration, tests are re-run. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/10/webstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2941/

Comment: 2017.3, but there is no --watch specified in my configuration. so I'm a bit puzzled.. is watch default behavior? must it be manually disabled?

Comment: ah... never mind, I found it. i had specified it in my package.json, thank you!

Comment: any help on this?